# python read from fileinput to build a list, None type error

Tags: python, file-io

I have a file with one gene name in each line, and I want to build a list with each gene name as an element of the list. I used fileinput

```
def get_gene_symbols():
    gene_symbols = []
    for line in fileinput.input():
        gene_symbol = line.strip()  # assume each line contains only one gene symbol
        print gene_symbol
        gene_symbols = gene_symbols.append(gene_symbol)
    return gene_symbols

print get_gene_symbols()
```

my input.txt file looks like this:

```
    cat input.txt         
    CCDC83 
    MAST3 
    FLOT1 
    RPL11 
    ZDHHC20 
    LUC7L3 
    SNORD49A  
    CTSH 
    ACOT8
```

when I use python test.py input.txt to invoke it, it gave me error:

```
tommy@tommy-ThinkPad-T420[scripts_general_use] python test.py input.txt
CCDC83
MAST3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 16, in <module>
    print get_gene_symbols()
  File "test.py", line 11, in get_gene_symbols
    gene_symbols = gene_symbols.append(gene_symbol)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'
```

first two gene names are printed out, but not others. what's wrong? I am a newbie of 
python. Thank you! I am using python 2.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `append` method returns `None`, **not** the appended list. You are reassigning your `gene_symbols` list to be `None` and then attempting to append to `gene_symbols` which is now `NoneType`, hence the error. You want to instead change:

```
gene_symbols = gene_symbols.append(gene_symbol)
```

to:

```
gene_symbols.append(gene_symbol)
```

Comment: Thank you! I got it. another question is that why the first two lines are print out and python throws an error when the third line is read?

Comment: The first `print` works fine as you have not yet done any appending. Then you set `genetypes` to be `None`. The second `print` also works as you have not yet attempted to append to `NoneType` at this stage. The third `print` never happens as it occurs after you attempt to append to `genetypes` which is now `NoneType`.